# Parse and format the Data in bash or C-shell

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, foreach, csh

I have the input data in below format from command and I need to parse it using foreach loop or awk or any efficient technique to get desired output as shown below.

Input Data:

```
General Information
  Job = Job1
  Workstation Folder = /test/
  Workstation = xyz-test
  Monitored = No
  Requires Confirmation = No
  Interactive = No
  Critical = No
Runtime Information
  Status = Successful
  Internal Status = SUCC
  Not Satisfied Dependencies = 0
  Rerun Options =
  Rerun on the same workstation = No
  Information =
  Promoted = No
  Return Code = 0
  Return Code Mapping Expression =
Time Information
  Actual Start = 04/30/2023 00:00:05 TZ EDT
  Earliest Start = 04/30/2023 00:00:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start = 04/30/2023 23:59:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start Action = Suppress
  Maximum Duration =
  Maximum Duration Action =
  Minimum Duration =
  Minimum Duration Action =
  Critical Latest Start =
Recovery Information
  Action = Stop
  Message =
  Job Definition =
  Workstation Folder =
  Workstation =
Extra Run Information
  -
General Information
  Job = Job2
  Workstation Folder = /test/
  Workstation = xyz-test
  Monitored = No
  Requires Confirmation = No
  Interactive = No
  Critical = No
Runtime Information
  Status = Running
  Internal Status = EXEC
  Not Satisfied Dependencies = 0
  Rerun Options = Every run
  Rerun on the same workstation = No
  Information = Every
  Promoted = No
  Return Code =
  Return Code Mapping Expression =
Time Information
  Actual Start = 04/30/2023 19:17:12 TZ EDT
  Earliest Start = 04/30/2023 19:15:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start = 04/30/2023 23:59:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start Action = Suppress
  Maximum Duration =
  Maximum Duration Action =
  Minimum Duration =
  Minimum Duration Action =
  Critical Latest Start =
Recovery Information
  Action = Stop
  Message =
  Job Definition =
  Workstation Folder =
  Workstation =
  Extra Run Information
  -
```

Output can be populated by parsing input data and using input fields as shown below.

Eg. $Job(From General Information).$Actual Start(From Time Information).$Actual Start(From Time Information).$Internal Status(From Runtime Information)

Expected Output:

```
Job1.04/30/2023.00:00:05.SUCC
Job2.04/30/2023.19:17:12.EXEC
```

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    RS = "General Information"
    FS = "\n"
    OFS = "."
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ "Job =") {
            gsub(".*= ", "", $i)
            a = $i
        } else if ($i ~ "Actual Start =") {
            gsub(".*= ", "", $i)
            gsub(" TZ.*", "", $i)
            gsub(" ", ".", $i)
            b = $i
        } else if ($i ~ "Internal Status =") {
            gsub(".*= ", "", $i)
            c = $i
        }
    }
    print a, b, c
}' logfile.txt
Job1.04/30/2023.00:00:05.SUCC
Job2.04/30/2023.19:17:12.EXEC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
General Information
  Job = Job1
  Workstation Folder = /test/
  Workstation = xyz-test
  Monitored = No
  Requires Confirmation = No
  Interactive = No
  Critical = No
Runtime Information
  Status = Successful
  Internal Status = SUCC
  Not Satisfied Dependencies = 0
  Rerun Options =
  Rerun on the same workstation = No
  Information =
  Promoted = No
  Return Code = 0
  Return Code Mapping Expression =
Time Information
  Actual Start = 04/30/2023 00:00:05 TZ EDT
  Earliest Start = 04/30/2023 00:00:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start = 04/30/2023 23:59:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start Action = Suppress
  Maximum Duration =
  Maximum Duration Action =
  Minimum Duration =
  Minimum Duration Action =
  Critical Latest Start =
Recovery Information
  Action = Stop
  Message =
  Job Definition =
  Workstation Folder =
  Workstation =
Extra Run Information
  -
General Information
  Job = Job2
  Workstation Folder = /test/
  Workstation = xyz-test
  Monitored = No
  Requires Confirmation = No
  Interactive = No
  Critical = No
Runtime Information
  Status = Running
  Internal Status = EXEC
  Not Satisfied Dependencies = 0
  Rerun Options = Every run
  Rerun on the same workstation = No
  Information = Every
  Promoted = No
  Return Code =
  Return Code Mapping Expression =
Time Information
  Actual Start = 04/30/2023 19:17:12 TZ EDT
  Earliest Start = 04/30/2023 19:15:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start = 04/30/2023 23:59:00 TZ EDT
  Latest Start Action = Suppress
  Maximum Duration =
  Maximum Duration Action =
  Minimum Duration =
  Minimum Duration Action =
  Critical Latest Start =
Recovery Information
  Action = Stop
  Message =
  Job Definition =
  Workstation Folder =
  Workstation =
  Extra Run Information
  -
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="."}/Job =/{job=$3}/Actual Start =/{sdate=$4;stime=$5}/Internal Status =/{status=$4}$1=="-"{print job, sdate, stime, status}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Job1.04/30/2023.00:00:05.SUCC
Job2.04/30/2023.19:17:12.EXEC
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to use `.` character as output field separator (`OFS`) then when encountering line with `Job =` I save 3rd field in variable `job`, for `Actual Start =` I save date and time in variables `sdate` and `stime`, for line with `Internal Status =` I save 4th field in variable `status`, for line where 1st field is `-` I `print` collected data.
**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that job name has never whitespace character AND all mentioned data are present AND `-` in 1st field is terminator, if this does not hold ignore this answer entirely

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*